# RemoteServiceException occurs in Galaxy Note10 Lite from android app

Tags: android

I am getting android.app.RemoteServiceException in my android app, where as I am not using LocalBroadcasts.

```
Fatal Exception: android.app.RemoteServiceException: can't deliver broadcast
   at android.app.ActivityThread.throwRemoteServiceException(ActivityThread.java:2146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:310)
   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2372)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8633)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:567)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

Happening 100% in Galaxy Note10 Lite with Android 12.

Please any help here would be appreciated.

Comment: http://android--kotlin.blogspot.com/2018/12/fatal-exception-android-app-remoteserviceexception-cant-deliver-broadcast.html